# "Exception Occurred" with addSiteAccount1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yodlee

After having gotten a site's login form from getSiteLoginForm, I'm attempting to add a site, but I'm receiving

`{ :errorOccurred=>"true", :exceptionType=>"Exception Occurred", :referenceCode=>"_fa9ede97-1792-45ca-b147-005ec4002d33" }`

The URL I'm POSTing to (in Rails) is:
https://consolidatedsdk.yodlee.com/yodsoap/srest/private-fairshare/v1.0/jsonsdk/SiteAccountManagement/addSiteAccount1

and this is the POST data:

`cobSessionToken=REDACTED
    userSessionToken=REDACTED
    siteId=11671
    credentialFields.enclosedType=com.yodlee.common.FieldInfoSingle
    credentialFields[0][displayName]=User Name
    credentialFields[0][fieldType.typeName]=TEXT
    credentialFields[0][isEditable]=true
    credentialFields[0][name]=LOGIN
    credentialFields[0][value]=testuser
    credentialFields[0][valueIdentifier]=LOGIN
    credentialFields[0][valueMask]=LOGIN_FIELD
    credentialFields[1][displayName]=Password
    credentialFields[1][fieldType.typeName]=IF_PASSWORD
    credentialFields[1][isEditable]=true
    credentialFields[1][name]=PASSWORD
    credentialFields[1][value]=testpass
    credentialFields[1][valueIdentifier]=PASSWORD
    credentialFields[1][valueMask]=LOGIN_FIELD`

I've triple checked the parameters, and they seem to match up with the [documentation](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/addSiteAccount1).

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the documentation it looks like there's a mismatch in the format of your parameters.

For example, you have the field `credentialFields[0][displayName]`, but in the documentation it's referred to as `credentialFields[0].displayName`. Is is possible that the API expects fields in this format?

If the API does expect fields in the `credentialFields[0][displayName]` then it would make sense for the `credentialFields.enclosedType` field to follow the same format. In that case it should be `credentialFields[enclosedType]`.

Comment: Indeed, the difference was sending: `credentialFields[0].fieldType.typeName=TEXT` vs `credentialFields[0][fieldType.typeName]=TEXT`.